# Form renders with array of objects but errors when I type

Tags: reactjs

I render a form with an array of objects to populate the form when it first loads using `componentWillReceiveProps`. The form renders correctly with no errors. `this.state.data` renders an array of objects that looks like:

```
this.state.data: (3) [Object, Object, Object]
[{
company: Company A,
title: Title A,
uniqueId: uniqueId A
},
{
company: Company A,
title: Title A,
uniqueId: uniqueId A
}]
```

When I type in the form `handleInputChange` appears to be causing the error that fires with each keyboard entry `Uncaught TypeError: positions.map is not a function at PositionList  StatelessComponent.ReactCompositeComponent.js.StatelessComponent.render` and when I submit the form `this.state.data` appears to not have changed as it returns and array of objects that looks like:

```
this.state.data: (3) [Object, Object, Object]
    [{
    company: Company A,
    title: Title A,
    uniqueId: uniqueId A
    },
    {
    company: Company A,
    title: Title A,
    uniqueId: uniqueId A
    },
{
"": "Whatever text I've typed in to the input field"
}]
```

Please see the full form render below. Although it's long I think I need to add a fair amount of detail to show the problem.

```
function PositionItem(props) {
  // Correct! There is no need to specify the key here:
  return <li>
    <input type="text" defaultValue={props.company} onChange={props.onChange} />
  </li>;
}


function PositionList(props) {
  const positions = props.positions;

  const listPositions = positions.map((position) =>
  // Correct! Key should be specified inside the array.
  <PositionItem key={position.uniqueId.toString()}
    company={position.company}
    uniqueId={position.uniqueId}
    onChange={props.onChange}
  />
);

return (
  <ul>
    {listPositions}
  </ul>
);
}

export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };

    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const profileCandidateCollection = nextProps.profileCandidate;
    const careerHistoryPositions = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.careerHistoryPositions;

    const positions = careerHistoryPositions.map((position) =>
    ({
      uniqueId: position.uniqueId || '',
      company: position.company || '',
      title: position.title || ''
    }));
    this.setState({
      data: positions
    })
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    const data = {...this.state.data, ...{[name]: value}};

    this.setState({
      data: data
    });
  }

  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("click", this.state.data);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.state.data: ', this.state.data);
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="careerHistoryForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <PositionList positions={this.state.data} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
          <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </form>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting data to an object then trying to call `.map` on it.

`.map` only works on arrays.

It looks like you want to replace this line:

```
const data = {...this.state.data, ...{[name]: value}};
```

with this line:

```
const data = [...this.state.data, {[name]: value}];
```

Comment: How do i append the array?

Comment: The last line of my answer

Comment: Sorry Andy I'm still learning here. So in `componentWillReceiveProps` I want to remove map and  add in `const data = [...this.state.data, {[name]: value}]; `. That doesn't make sense to me. Could you put up exactly what is should look like?

Comment: Ok, now I get 2 errors. First with each keyboard stroke I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined Array.map  PositionList` and when I submit the form it appears as though the append creates a new object with each key stroke.